# Input directive event on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create directive for `input`. I need to change class name if an input is not empty:

```
return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        elem.find('input, textarea').bind('focus', function() {
            elem.find('label').addClass('active');
        });

        elem.find('input, textarea').bind('blur', function(self) {
            if (self.target.value == '') elem.find('label').removeClass('active');
        });

        elem.find('input, textarea').bind('change', function(self) {
            if (self.target.value != '') elem.find('label').addClass('active');
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my input:

```
<div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
```

`Focus and blur` work fine. But `change` doesn't. On load `value = ''`. But my `$scope.name` is not empty.

How can I change class name if `ng-model` is not empty on load?

**UPDATE:**

```
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (elem.find('input, textarea').val() != '') elem.find('label').addClass('active');
        }, 100);
```

It works. But I'm thinking maybe in some old browsers it should be 200ms or 1000ms...

Comment: tried add ng-class="{ 'active': name}" on the label element?

Comment: @sdfacre, I thought about it but I have tons of inputs. It's why I use the directive for label class. I'd like to have only one statement for this except tons of ng-class="{ 'active': name}"

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `$timeout(function () { ... })` with 0 second waiting, or `$scope.$evalAsync()`.

More information you can find at 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm